# Maven3: run plugin as root user

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea, glassfish-4

I use IntelliJ Idea for developing, and now i want to use maven project for WAR packaging and deploying to Glassfish4 server. After latest update of OSX ([v.10.10.3](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21343)), glassfish4 must be started from sudouser, so i have a question: How can i pass to maven that this plugin (`glassfish:start-domain`) must be running from root?

I try to run this command in terminal, but it doesn't help
    `sudo mvn glassfish:start-domain`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't help" ?

Comment: @khmarbaise mvn runs from sudo, yes. but glassfish not starting. only way to start it - command `sudo ./asadmin start-domain`, i think that glassfish plugin for maven start with command `./asadmin ...` an get's error.